# jQuery POST to Node.JS Fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm trying to expand my horizons by getting familiar with node.js (I'm a .NET developer by profession), and I'm having trouble with what I assumed would be a simple POST example. I do have experience with jQuery, so node.js is the one relative unknown for me in this sample website I'm building.

The node.JS server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.logger());
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/PRB_Presentation'));

app.post('/GetPage', function(request, response){
    console.log(request.body.pageNumber);
    response.send(request.body.pageNumber);
});

var port = 80;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port: ' + port);
```

My client-side jQuery logic:

```
function getPage(pageNumber){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/GetPage',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ pageNumber: pageNumber })
        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log("Success: " + data);
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }).always(function() {
            console.log("Done!");
        })
        ;
    };
```

With my node.js server running, I do see the page number I send getting output to the console window correctly, but this is what I'm getting client-side:

> Error: unknown
>   Done!

I assume I am doing something incredibly simple wrong here, but I can't quite figure it out.

**EDIT**

- request.body.pageNumber contains a single numeric digit (for example,
  2)
- textStatus in fail() is simply "error"

Comment: A few questions: what's in `request.body.pageNumber`? Aside from that, in your `fail()` handler, what do `jqXHR` and `textStatus` contain?

Comment: what from jqXHR are you interested in? responseText is empty and responseJSON is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you're getting an error is because you're supplying a number in `res.send()`. Doing so sends the value as the HTTP status code, rather than the response body.

```
res.send(200);   -> HTTP 200 OK
res.send('200'); -> 200
```

The `send()` method accepts two arguments. If you supply one and it's a numerical value, then it will be interpreted as the HTTP status code to send. What you might find more applicable to what you're trying to do is `res.json()`.

```
app.post('/path', function(req, res) {
  res.json(request.body.page);
});
```

Otherwise, force the number to be sent as a string:

```
app.post('/path', function(req, res) {
  res.send('' + request.body.page);
});
```

Comment: Perfect! I figured out on my own by playing with it that by switching it to `res.send(request.body)` I was able to get a successful response, but you answered the follow-up question: why. Thanks